# How to extract a raw apk out of installed application?(Raw for reverse eng purpose)

Tags: apk, java, android-studio

So I developed an application but my hard drive failed and I lost access to project resources, but I had it previously installed on my phone through android studio debugging process.

Now I want to extract a raw apk version out of my phone, Is there any way?

NOTE that any regular apk extraction through Google Play applications outputs a ~700kb apk of my project that lacks resources and cant be reversed, while it has to be ~4.4mb.

Comment: On Stackoverflow this question has been answered several times: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43342330/150978 Note that `adb shell pm path <packagename> may list multiple APK files if the app is a split APK file. Then you need all of them.

Comment: @Robert thanks for your answer Robert, my bad. shall i remove this one?

Comment: You can just leave the question as it is - in the end it is a valid question and it is on-topic. May be some one other encounters it and gets directed to the answer.